# Delphi-TeeChart : Marks.DrawItem not working

Tags: delphi, teechart

I'd like to draw marks in `Chart.ChartAfterDraw` using `Aseries.Marks.DrawItem` method. I'm using the following code.

```
procedure TMyForm.ChartAfterDraw(Sender: TObject);
var
  mark : TTextShape;
begin
  mark := TTextShape.Create(Chart);
  mark.Font := ClickedSeries.Marks.Font;
  ClickedSeries.Marks.DrawItem(mark,
                              clRed,
                              'pippo',
                              ClickedSeries.Marks.Positions[ ClickedTask ] );


end;
```

But as you can see in figure below mark is created fine, in correct position, but its text is not printed.

[image]

In debug mod when cursor go past the end of `TMyForm.ChartAfterDraw` the following message appear.

[image]

This sounds like an error occured in `Marks.DrawItem` method. Unfortunately i'm using TeeChart Lite, so i cant't see where that method fails (if it really fails)

Can you help me? Thank you.

P.s. I'm using XE5

Comment: If you click `Ignore` in that dialog, do you then get an exception message?

Comment: Do you have other code where you set your pen/font/brush?  If so, please add it to your question. If not, you'll need to set those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be easier to directly draw your texts/marks using `Chart1.Canvas.Rectangle()` and `Chart1.Canvas.TextOut()` functions, but here you have an example using `Marks.DrawItem()` function. Note you had to create and initialize a `TSeriesMarkPosition` to pass it to the `Marks.DrawItem()`.

```
uses Series;

type
  TShapeAccess=class(TCustomTextShape);

var ClickedSeries: TChartSeries;
    ClickedTask: Integer;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var i: Integer;
begin
  Chart1.View3D:=false;

  for i:=0 to 3 do
    with Chart1.AddSeries(TPointSeries) do
      FillSampleValues;
end;

procedure TForm1.Chart1Click(Sender: TObject);
var i: Integer;
begin
  for i:=0 to Chart1.SeriesCount-1 do
  begin
    ClickedTask:=Chart1[i].Clicked(Chart1.GetCursorPos.X, Chart1.GetCursorPos.Y);
    if ClickedTask>-1 then
    begin
      ClickedSeries:=Chart1[i];
      Break;
    end;
  end;
  Chart1.Draw;
end;

procedure TForm1.Chart1AfterDraw(Sender: TObject);
var
  mark : TTextShape;
  position: TSeriesMarkPosition;
  tmpString: String;
begin
  if (ClickedSeries<>nil) and (ClickedTask>-1) and (ClickedTask<ClickedSeries.Count-1) then
  begin
    tmpString:='pippo';

    mark := TTextShape.Create(Chart1);
    mark.Text:=tmpString;
    mark.Font := ClickedSeries.Marks.Font;
    TShapeAccess(mark).CalcBounds(Chart1);

    position:=TSeriesMarkPosition.Create;
    position.LeftTop.X:=ClickedSeries.CalcXPos(ClickedTask);
    position.LeftTop.Y:=ClickedSeries.CalcYPos(ClickedTask);
    position.Width:=Chart1.Canvas.TextWidth(tmpString)+2;
    position.Height:=Chart1.Canvas.TextHeight(tmpString)+4;

    ClickedSeries.Marks.DrawItem(mark, clRed, tmpString, position);
  end;
end;
```